# Simple wire protocol, what's a guy to do?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, zeromq

I have a simple server written in C.  It's main purpose is to communicate with some business partners over a proprietary protocol.  For that reason and a few others, it must be written in C.  I have a number of other processes, however, written in other languages (e.g. Python) that must communicate with the server (locally, on the same Linux server).

What are the best options for cross-language IPC in this scenario?  Specifically, I think I have a handle on transport technologies: Unix domain sockets, named pipes, shared memory, ZeroMQ (Crossroads).  I'm more interested in the best way to implement the protocol, in order to keep the C code small and maintainable, while still allowing communication from other languages.

**Edit**: there seems to be some confusion.  I'm **not** interested in discussion of pros/cons of domain sockets, shared memory et. al.  I **am** interested in msgpack (thanks unwind), and other technologies/approaches for implementing the wire protocol.

Comment: Wild guess, sockets if you want to transfer data serially, shared memory+shared semaphore if you want faster and more random ipc.

Comment: OK, so what languages do you need, and what is required from the protocol? If it's just C & Python on Linux, you can trivially use fixed-size structures and be done with it.

Comment: Go is actually the primary other one, haskell is a nice to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to optimize (=select the "best") when the requirements are unknown. You do state that your goal is to keep the C code "small and maintainable", which seems to imply that you should look for a library. Perhaps [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) over a local socket?

Also, your basic premise that the server must be written in C because you have a proprietary protocol seems ... weird, at least.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: What you need is a "serialization framework", i.e. something can turn a memory structure into a byte stream. The best candidates are:

- [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)
- [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Pros/cons:

**Protocol Buffers**

- `+` Fast
- `+` Easy to version (which you'll start to love very much when you need to make a change to your message format for the first time and which you will curse to hell before that)
- `-` Solves many problems which you don't know about, yet. That makes the API a bit "strange". I assure you, there are very good reasons for what and how they do it but you will feel confused sometimes.

I don't know much about MessagePack.

Lastly:

**JSON**

- `+` Any language out there can read and write JSON data.
- `+` Human readable without tools
- `-` somewhat slow
- `-` the format is very flexible but if you need to make big changes, you need to find a strategy to figure out what format (= which fields) a message has when you read it.

As for the transport layer:

Pros/cons:

**Shared memory**

- `+` Fastest option
- `-` You need a second channel (like a semaphore) to tell the other process that the data is now ready
- `-` gets really ugly when you try to connect more then two processes
- `-` OS specific

**Named pipes**

- `+` Very easy to set up
- `+` Fairly fast
- `-` Only allows two processes to talk ... or rather one process to talk to another in a single direction. If you need bi-directional communication, you need several pipes

**Sockets**

- `+` Pretty easy to set up
- `+` Available for all and any languages
- `+` Allows remote access (not all processes need to be on the same machine)
- `+` Two-way communication with one server and several processes
- `-` Slower than shmem and pipes

**ZeroMQ**

- `+` Like sockets but better
- `+` Modern API (not that old IPC/socket junk)
- `+` Support for many languages...
- `-` ...but not all

If you can I'd suggest to try ZeroMQ because it's a modern framework that solves many of the problems that you'll encounter with the older technologies.

If that fails, I'd try sockets next. They are easy, well supported and docile.

Comment: Sorry, was hidden too well under things that you're not interested in :-)

Comment: I'm using ZeroMQ and Protocol Buffers for similar purposes.  They are working great, makes prototyping a lot faster compared to low level sockets and manual byte parsing.  I couldn't be happier with ProtoBuf.  ZeroMQ is also great but it has some weird quirks.

Comment: +1 for the pb and zmq combo. I use it all over the place with code that interfaces between c++ and python.